# For Loop Time Complexity

Tags: performance, time-complexity

I was curious to find out if you have a two way iterating for loop does it decrease the time complexity and if so by how much? I know most people do a standard for loop

```
For (int index = 0; index < count - 1; index++)
{
    if ( Something(index) == "Hello")
    {
        return true
    }
}
Return False
```

How much better would it be if you have a two way iterating for loop to reduce time?

```
 int index2 = count - 1;
 For ( int index = 0; index < count - 1; index++)
 {
     if(Something(index) == "Hello" || Something(index2) == "Hello"
     {
         return true;
     }
     index2--;
     if ( index = index2)
     {
        return  false; 
     }  
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given no extra information about the underlying data in the array both actually will be the same order of complexity in terms of array lookups and comparison operations. The order of complexity is not about how many times the loop runs through but rather the total number of operations performed. The first version loops `n` times and does 1 operation per loop which is `n*1` operations *in total*. The second does `n/2` loops with 2 operations per loop which is `(n/2)*2=n` operations. You can see that these are the same.

However when you practically implement it the second version will do worse on many architectures because of extra cache misses. If the start and end are far away you end up having to go back to main memory to load it into the cache a lot. This is much more expensive than a simple comparison. This is why compilers might optimize the code by transforming it to do something like the first form.

Comment: Ok I am just assuming the data is just a array of strings and nothing else. I was trying to figure a better way to reduce time complexity using a for loop instead of the standard O(n).

Comment: @Kyle but you fundamentally can't improve on a O(n) worst case. This is because if there's an array of length `n` and you want to see if it contains a string you have to be able to check all `n` items in order to be sure that the item is indeed not there.

Comment: Then outside of a binary search what would be a better way to reduce the time complexity going through an array? I mean you can implement a Mergesort to reduce the 0(N) of a bubble sort. What would be the alternative to doing the same thing for a iteration?

Comment: @Kyle to be clear, if you cut n operations, which is O(n), to n/2, you still get something that's O(n). It might go twice as fast, and that might be important, but it makes no difference from a big-O standpoint. To be even *more* pedantic, you could cut it down to 1 operation flat and it would *still* be O(n). it would also be O(1).

Comment: @Kyle if you *must read* every item of your array, your algorithm is Omega(n). You cannot improve this as long as your algorithm has the property that it must read every item of your array. Binary search does not need to read every item of the array and it is not Omega(n).

Comment: @Kyle in the case of a sorted array you know a lot more about the underlying data which you can then exploit to get a lower big-O complexity because you don't need to check each an every element anymore. Without knowing that extra information the worst case for testing if an element is present has to remain O(n). Don't be discouraged, keep thinking critically about improving performance, it will help you write better code as the average case running time is important.

Comment: Does this mean that it is always better to remove at index over a doing the standard remove for time complexity? Remove at would be faster since we look for the index rather then a remove(Dog) would have to find the dog first to remove it correct?

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity is the same, since the complexity is by definition independent of any constant factor (like 2).

Comment: So for a 100 count list which would take you 50 iterations with a two way iterating loop would be the same as if you 100 went through the loop 100 times?

Comment: I think that's pedantic. "Time complexity" often refers to "asymptotic, up to a constant factor" but the OP is clearly asking about a factor of 2, which I think is fair to call "time complexity." If I'm trying to cut my server bill from $2000 to $1000, a factor of 2 becomes quite important...